# Style Property in Js File

Tags: javascript, html

I am working with Events and try to access class in js file. I am using Visual Code.
style property is not displaying after dot operator with menu class.
My menu cla[image]

Below is the code for script.js
script.js

```
/** @type {HTMLElement} */
let menuBtn = document.querySelector('.menu-btn');
let menu = document.querySelector('.menu');
let menuStatus = false;
//create a function to toggle the menu
function menuToggle(){
    if(menuStatus==false){
    
        menu.s
    }

}
```

Below is my index.html file.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="en">
 <head>
     <meta charset="UTF-8">
     <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
     <title>Document</title>
     
     
 </head>
 <body>
     <a class ="menu-btn" href="#">Menu</a>
     <div class="menu">
         <ul>
             <li><a href="#">This is a Link 1</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">This is a Link 2</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">This is a Link 3</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">This is a Link 4</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">This is a Link 5</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">This is a Link 6</a></li>
         </ul>

     </div>

  <script src = "script.js"></script>   
 </body>
 </html>
```

Please tell me how can I resolve the issue because many times visual studio code does not display the properties after dot operator just like style and value.

Comment: Do you have problem with your code or vs code?

Comment: I don't think so

Comment: It does make things easier but if you know a property why not just write it. Also vscode might be displaying it but not on top so try scrolling down the list. I think you are a beginner so, you should focus on learning and not autocompletion.

Comment: Thank you Bajaj after writing by self my problem has solved because VS is not displaying such kind of properties.